# GIMP: Pastes into a zone within a layer?

Tags: gimp, layers

So I have two images, and I want to put them into one big image.  What I did was I

1. Cut the contents of one image.
2. Increased the canvas size of the other image to x2.
3. Pasted the image I have.
4. Tried to use the move tool to place the pasted layer.

When I move the pasted layer around, it goes behind the transparency layer on the canvas.  How do I make that not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new layer and then paste the floating layer into it.